# JavaScript and jQuery scrolling issue in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

I just launched http://tweetmp.org.au/ with a stack of new features, including the MP Spotlight you can see on the Homepage

Every few seconds, the following code is run,

```
// get the next it
var nextId = ids[Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length)];

$.get('/GetSummary?id=' + nextId, function (result) {
    if (result) {
        $('#memberList').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).html(result).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }
});
```

which goes and fetches the next MP and fades the old one out and the new one in. Looks great!

***BUT***

If you scroll down to the bottom of the page and wait till the MP spotlight refreshes, the browser scrolls back to #memberList

Does anyone know what's causing this? How can I stop it from scrolling?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it.

I changed the fadeIn and fadeOut to fadeTo between 0.01 and 1.0

It appears jQuery sets display:none when the opacity reaches 0, thus decreasing the size of the page (forcing the scroll up)

Comment: Thanks for telling us how you fixed it. I tend to avoid fadeOut/fadeTo and all the default setups. I prefer have more control, e.g. $(elem).animate({opacity:0.7});

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.get('/GetSummary?id=' + nextId, function (result) {
    $('#memberList').fadeOut('slow').html(result).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: This won't work as the author intended. The HTML will be added before the element is completely faded out.